# Algorithm idea for pandas python

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas

The actual `pandas` dataset looks like:

```
index household carID   waypoint

497   201248    2       from home       15
498   201248    2                       18
499   201248    2       to home         19
500   201248    1       from home       10
501   201248    1       to home         10
502   201248    1                       19
503   201248    1       to home         0
504   201248    2       from home       8
505   201248    2                       9
506   201248    2       to home         9
```

Here you see, that `carID` `1` is away from `10:00` to `0:00`. So an absent time of `14` hours:

For `carID` `2` it gets complicated. It is absent from `8:00` to `9` and again from `15:00` to `19:00`

What I want is to compute the absent time of `CarID` `2`: From the first time it drives `from home`, `08:00`, until the last time it drives `to home` `19:00`.

So the final DataFrame should look like:

```
index household carID   waypoint            absent
497   201248    2       from home       15   
498   201248    2                       18
499   201248    2       to home         19   4
500   201248    1       from home       10
501   201248    1       to home         10
502   201248    1                       19
503   201248    1       to home         0    14
504   201248    2       from home       8
505   201248    2                       9
506   201248    2       to home         9    11 (because the final end time is 19:00 see upper table)
```

Do anyone have an idea? It would help, if I could sort inside the specific household number (not index).

Comment: Please, format your data frames representation.

Answer (score 0):

I named the 4th column in your df  'time'.

```
df['time_24'] = df['time'] # a new column having times from 01 to 24 instead of 00
df.loc[df['time'] == 0, 'time_24'] = 24 # replacing 00 with 24
df.join(df.groupby('carID')['time_24'].max() - df.groupby('carID')['time_24'].min(), on='carID', rsuffix='_r')
df['absent'] = df['time_24_r']
```

The absent column returns the time you want. This work assuming the logic that minimum of from home times are always less than maximum of to home times. Otherwise, you need to groupby waypoint as well.